# Difference between Url.RouteUrl() & Url.Action() in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am in the process of generating a URL dynamically in my cshtml page.
What is the difference between Url.RouteUrl() & Url.Action()?

Which one should I use to generate the URL & what difference do both have in terms of implementation ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

`RouteUrl` generated the url based on route name. If you have multiple routes with similar parameters the `Action` method may pick a wrong one - it works based on the order of route definitions. This may take place when your routes have optional parameters.

If you want to make sure that a certain route url will be used you need to call `RouteUrl` passing this route name. Route names are unique and clearly identifies a route.

One more difference is that `Action` is MVC specific (it uses controller and action names), while `RouteUrl` is generic is and can be used without MVC (you can have routing in WebForms).

Answer (score 17):

`Url.RouteUrl` allows you to specify a particular route by name. This will *force* the usage of that route. `Url.Action` will simply pick the first route that matches the criteria.

Comment: This also means Url.RouteUrl is better in terms of performance over Url.Action